# grep for lines with all words greater than 10 characters in length

Tags: text-processing, grep

I need a `grep` command that finds all lines that only contain words with lengths greater than 10.

this is the `grep` I wrote to find words bigger than 10 characters.

```
grep -E '(\w{11,})' input
```

How would I manipulate this command to include every word on the line?

Comment: Dear **Mike**, please consider [accepting the answer which solved your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking ✔sign next to the answer. thank you

Comment: yes mike, please :) The answer is a good one even after 5 years @αғsнιη (though mike is last seen 4 years ago :( )

Answer (score 9):

Your condition might be more easily expressed in the contrapositive: instead of including lines where all words have length > 10, exclude those lines which have a word with length <= 10. Since grep supports both negation and word-matching, this could be written as, say:

```
grep -vwE '\w{1,10}'
```

- `-v` negates the match
- `-w` means that the regex should match a whole word

As Sundeep noted, we should use `{1,10}` to avoid matching the empty string (and thus every line).

Comment: use `{1,10}` ... see the output for `echo 'fooo bar ;' | grep -vwE '\w{,2}'` and `echo 'fooo bar ;' | grep -vwE '\w{1,2}'`